# Does a git repo always have to be in its own directory

Tags: git, github

*I would like to have multiple files in a folder with are managed by different git repositories. Is it possible?*

I have the following folder structure for a project. It is part of a Git repository:

```
plugins/
 - plugin.a.php
 - plugin.b.php
 - plugin.c.php
```

I would like `plugin.b.php` to be part of another repo. For example, I want the development of this plugin to be hosted on github. To use and develop concurrently on different projects.

When I use **a git submodule** for `plugin.b.php`, I need an empty folder to init the submodule, so I have a structure of:

```
plugins/
 - plugin.a.php
 newfolder/
     - plugin.b.php
 - plugin.c.php
```

`plugin.b.php` will not load as, for example, my App only loads files from the root of `plugins/`. And, I don't want to have to modify the App.

Is there anyway to do this? I can think of lots of situations where I would like to use a similar workflow. Even having both `plugin.b.php` and `plugin.c.php` in different repos.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`--git-dir`, `--work-tree`, `GIT_DIR` and `GIT_WORK_TREE`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/).
You should be able to create a repository somewhere else and set it's working directory to your normal path. Just add the one file to the second repository.

Comment: @tanascius thanks. Marked your answer correct. Used a different solution, posted it below.

Answer (score 2):

See @tanascius' answer which provides the correct answer to using multiple git repos in one directory.

I am tentativly answering my own question in relation to: the question's example and GitHub. As there is a small caveat...

It is not possible for `pluginb` & `pluginc` to have same named files in the `plugins` folder. Although this is unlikely, as github repos, they both have github README files causing a conflit.

For this *low file count* situation I've settled for using a symbolic link (and keeping the repos inside the main repo which is optional):

```
.git/
.gitignore = .repos/
.repos/
     .git/
     - pluginb/
         README
         plugin.b.php
     - pluginc/
         README
         plugin.c.php
plugins/
     - plugin.a.php
     - symbolic-link = plugin.b.php
     - symbolic-link = plugin.c.php
```